# Label elements based on class they belong to

Tags: json, dictionary, jq

I have a stream of elements `object_count.json` looking like:

```
{
    "name":"apple",
    "count":10
}
{
    "name":"potato",
    "count":18
}
{
    "name":"stone",
    "count:7
}
```

Separate from the stream, I have two files, each listing names of objects of its class:

```
cat fruits.txt
  apple
  peach

cat vegetables.txt
  potato
  tomato
```

**How can I construct a stream where each object from `object_count.json` is attributed with its respective class name?** I.e.:

```
{
    "name":"apple",
    "count":10
    "class":"fruit"
}
{
    "name":"potato",
    "count":18
    "class":"vegetable"
}
{
    "name":"stone",
    "count":7
    "class":"other"
}
```

We can assume there is only one entry per object name in `object_count.json`.

---

I would most prefer a solution which:

- works well 3, 4 and more classes--each still listed in a separate file; it's OK if each class is hardcoded
- `object_count.json` is considered an input stream, while `{fruits|vegetables}.txt` are provided each as a separate `--rawfile` argument

Version as reported by JQ:

```
 $ jq --version
 jq-1.6
```

---

I managed to feed the class file as an command-line argument, but failing to find a proper `join` / `in` expression which will work and solve the problem:

```
cat object_count.json | jq -n --rawfile fruits "fruits.txt" '($fruits | split("\n") | map(select(. != "")) | sort) as $frts | inputs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with the updated question, here is a solution that avoids slurping the contents of object_count.json.

### dictionary.jq

```
def trim: sub("^ +"; "") | sub(" +$"; "");

def dictionary(s):
  reduce (s | trim | select(length>0)) as $in ({};
     (input_filename | sub(".txt";"") | sub("s$";"")) as $class
     | .[$in] = $class );

dictionary(inputs)
```

### Invocation

```
jq --argfile class <(jq -n -R -f dictionary.jq *.txt)  '
 .class = ($class[.name] // "other")'  object_count.json
```

### Postscript

Using "other" as the default class name might be a requirement, but if not, then in situations like this, it would probably be preferable to go with the flow and use JSON's `null` as the default value for an object's key.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Coult you elaborate a bit: how does it work? `trim` seems to remove empty and blank lines; dictionary seem to construct a set of arrays out of input .txt files(?); the last clause is not very intuitive: `| .[$in] = $class`. The invocation is more or less intuitive; I only wonder whether the whole thing can be made with a single JQ process (not a huge deal though). Still curious why you preferred to not use `in` or `join` operators, which I originally hoped to learn about by example :-)

Comment: `sub` is like awk's `sub`; you can read about it and other details in the jq manual (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual). Having to deal with multiple hardcoded class names is too tedious for my taste. I'm more interested in simple solutions that are also clear even if only in retrospect. In this case we're constrained by some unfortunate limitations of jq.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a response to the original question. It allows for arbitrarily many "class" files, and requires only one invocation of jq.  For a solution that does not involve "slurping" the JSON stream, see elsewhere on this page.]

The tricky part here is managing the unknown number of .txt files.  Here, we'll assume we can write '*.txt' to capture them, so the invocation of jq will look like this:

```
jq -n -R -f program.jq --slurpfile input object_count.json *.txt
```

To construct the dictionary, we'll use the following helper functions:

```
def trim: sub("^ +"; "") | sub(" +$"; "");

# construct the dictionary
def dictionary(s):
  reduce (s | trim | select(length>0)) as $in ({};
     (input_filename | sub(".txt";"") | sub("s$";"")) as $class
     | .[$in] = $class );
```

Now the task reduces to the following three lines:

```
dictionary(inputs) as $class
| $input[]
| .class = ($class[.name] // "other")
```

Comment: 1. My plan was to supply each of `{fruits|vegetables}.txt` as a separate `--rawfile` argument. One of the reasons for doing so is that object_count.json is bit larger (hundreds of objects), while `{fruits|vegetables}.txt` are few dozens each, pure one-name-per-line file. Would structuring the JQ query for such a scenario make it more complex?

Comment: 2. Could you elaborate how each helper function actually works?

Comment: 3. For the purposes of the original question, we can assume that the number of classes (and therefore the .txt files) is hard-coded in the query / command invoking JQ.

Comment: If object_count.json only contains a few hundred (or even a few thousands) of objects, slurping the file will be fine.  The problem with using multiple --rawfile arguments is that you'd have to hardcode all the class names.  There are, of course, numerous other possibilities (e.g. you could preprocess the *.txt files into a single JSON file), but why not stick with a very simple and apparently adequate one?

Comment: Updated original question with my preferences from the above comments.